# accelerometer is sampled at high frequency , how to convert UTC time to float time?

Tags: python, pandas, accelerometer

```
 import pandas as pd
 df = pd.DataFrame(['Time':['16:47:55.510','16:47:55.511','16:47:55.410']})
 df

 output:
            Time
 0      16:47:55.510
 1      16:47:55.511
 2      16:47:55.410
```

how to convert this time values to float value using python?

Comment: To what float value exactly?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by float value?

Comment: I want all the values of Time column in nano second so that it will look like a float value just like for example   3333344.222           (   so that all information related to this format of time '16:47:55.510 ' will be recorded or utilized )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the time is in h:m:s.ms format you can do something like this:

```
hours, minutes, seconds = df.Time[0].split(':')
total_seconds = int(hours) * 3600 + int(minutes) * 60 + float(seconds)
```

Comment: But i want this in  nano second

Comment: Multiply the total_seconds by 1e9!

Comment: thanks bro i a have used and its working fine